# knockoutjs comparing current row element with previous row element

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel bound to a template as below and it shows all contents correctly. 
But what I like to do is if the current row Folder is same as previous row's Folder then I would like to put blank instead of repeating the same Folder. 
I've tried in the data-bind like this: "text: ($index() > 0 ? ($data[$index() - 1].Folder == $data.Folder ? '': $data.Folder) : '')
but it does not work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<table border="1">    
    <script type="text/html" id="content-template">  

        <tr data-bind="css: { 'firstRow': $index() % 2 }">
            <td><span data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Folder"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Location"></span></td>                    
        </tr>
    </script>
</table>
<div data-bind="visible: loaded()">        
    <div id="data" data-bind="template: { name: 'content-template', foreach: contents }"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, contents was declared as an obserableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax to access the contents array within the foreach block is incorrect:

`"text: ($index() > 0 ? ($data[$index() - 1].Folder == $data.Folder ? '': $data.Folder) : '')`.

$data is the current contents() observable array *element*, not the contents array itself. To access the contents array you can use:

```
$parent.contents()[$index()]
```

and to get the previous element if $index() > 0

```
$parent.contents()[$index()-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a function on the viewmodel to do the determination of visible or not -- it makes it easier to test and your `data-bind` attribute is simpler:

```
showItem: function(index) {
    if( index == 0 )
        return true;

    return this.contents[index - 1].Folder != this.contents[index].Folder;
}
```

Now bind the `visible` property to this function:

```
visible: $parent.showItem($index())
```

Here's a [jsFiddle showing a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/WB7U6/).

Comment: Assuming contents is an observable array, the code above should have () appended to each occurrence of contents. E.g. "return this.contents()[index - 1].Folder != this.contents()[index].Folder;"

Comment: @ChuckSchneider, correct, *if* 'contents' was an observable array.  In my example, I just used a regular array for simplicity (and the original question didn't indicate if an observable array was used).